# Linuxbrew: Bad address for executables that do exist - Tips for debugging

Tags: homebrew

I'm running WSL1 on Windows 11, and installed linuxbrew and some other apps using that.

Working in a terminal, if I try to run anything installed under linuxbrew, I get an error of the form:

```
gmaddock@EXP21623:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin$ unzip
bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/unzip: Bad address
```

Looking in the specified directory, I see that these executables are symlinks to another folder:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 gmaddock gmaddock   31 Nov  9 19:52 unzip -> ../Cellar/unzip/6.0_8/bin/unzip
lrwxrwxrwx 1 gmaddock gmaddock   34 Nov  9 19:52 unzipsfx -> ../Cellar/unzip/6.0_8/bin/unzipsfx
lrwxrwxrwx 1 gmaddock gmaddock   31 Nov 21 13:02 unzstd -> ../Cellar/zstd/1.5.5/bin/unzstd
```

If I go to that directory, I see the file and it is executable, but if I try to execute it there, I still get a bad address:

```
gmaddock@EXP21623:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/unzip/6.0_8/bin$ ls -la
total 440
drwxr-xr-x 1 gmaddock gmaddock   4096 Apr 19  2009 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 gmaddock gmaddock   4096 Nov  9 19:52 ..
-r-xr-xr-x 1 gmaddock gmaddock  26968 Nov  9 19:52 funzip
-r-xr-xr-x 1 gmaddock gmaddock 166760 Nov  9 19:52 unzip
-r-xr-xr-x 1 gmaddock gmaddock  80680 Nov  9 19:52 unzipsfx
-r-xr-xr-x 1 gmaddock gmaddock   2959 Apr 19  2009 zipgrep
-r-xr-xr-x 1 gmaddock gmaddock 166760 Nov  9 19:52 zipinfo
gmaddock@EXP21623:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/unzip/6.0_8/bin$ ./unzip
bash: ./unzip: Bad address
```

Oddly, if I `sudo unzip`, it does run, even though it's executable by all.

Any tips on what to try to resolve this?